# Using React Hooks, why are my event handlers firing with the incorrect state?

Tags: reactjs, event-listener, react-hooks, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

I'm trying to create a copy of this spinning `div` example using react hooks. https://codesandbox.io/s/XDjY28XoV

Here's my code so far

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [box, setBox] = useState(null);

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
  const [startAngle, setStartAngle] = useState(0);
  const [currentAngle, setCurrentAngle] = useState(0);
  const [boxCenterPoint, setBoxCenterPoint] = useState({});

  const setBoxCallback = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setBox(node)
    }
  }, [])

  // to avoid unwanted behaviour, deselect all text
  const deselectAll = () => {
    if (document.selection) {
      document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  }

  // method to get the positionof the pointer event relative to the center of the box
  const getPositionFromCenter = e => {
    const fromBoxCenter = {
      x: e.clientX - boxCenterPoint.x,
      y: -(e.clientY - boxCenterPoint.y)
    };
    return fromBoxCenter;
  }

  const mouseDownHandler = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const fromBoxCenter = getPositionFromCenter(e);
    const newStartAngle =
      90 - Math.atan2(fromBoxCenter.y, fromBoxCenter.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
    setStartAngle(newStartAngle);
    setIsActive(true);
  }

  const mouseUpHandler = e => {
    deselectAll();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (isActive) {
      const newCurrentAngle = currentAngle + (angle - startAngle);
      setIsActive(false);
      setCurrentAngle(newCurrentAngle);
    }
  }

  const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
    if (isActive) {
      const fromBoxCenter = getPositionFromCenter(e);
      const newAngle =
        90 - Math.atan2(fromBoxCenter.y, fromBoxCenter.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
      box.style.transform =
        "rotate(" +
        (currentAngle + (newAngle - (startAngle ? startAngle : 0))) +
        "deg)";
      setAngle(newAngle)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (box) {
      const boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect();
      // get the current center point
      const boxCenterX = boxPosition.left + boxPosition.width / 2;
      const boxCenterY = boxPosition.top + boxPosition.height / 2;

      // update the state
      setBoxCenterPoint({ x: boxCenterX, y: boxCenterY });
    }

    // in case the event ends outside the box
    window.onmouseup = mouseUpHandler;
    window.onmousemove = mouseMoveHandler;
  }, [ box ])

  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div
        className="box"
        onMouseDown={mouseDownHandler}
        onMouseUp={mouseUpHandler}
        ref={setBoxCallback}
      >
        Rotate
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Currently mouseMoveHandler is called with a state of `isActive = false` even though the state is actually true. How can I get this event handler to fire with the correct state?

Also, the console is logging the warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'mouseMoveHandler' and 'mouseUpHandler'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Why do I have to include component methods in the useEffect dependency array? I've never had to do this for other simpler component using React Hooks.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The Problem

> Why is `isActive` false?

```
const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
   if(isActive) {
       // ...
   }
};
```

(Note for convenience I'm only talking about `mouseMoveHandler`, but everything here applies to `mouseUpHandler` as well)

When the above code runs, a function instance is created, which pulls in the `isActive` variable via [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).  That variable is a constant, so if `isActive` is false when the function is defined, then it's *always* going to be `false` as long that function instance exists.

`useEffect` also takes a function, and that function has a constant reference to your `moveMouseHandler` function instance - so as long as that useEffect callback exists, it references a copy of `moveMouseHandler` where `isActive` is false.

When `isActive` changes, the component rerenders, and a new instance of `moveMouseHandler` will be created in which `isActive` is `true`.  However, `useEffect` only reruns its function if the dependencies have changed - in this case, the dependencies (`[box]`) have not changed, so the `useEffect` does not re-run and the version of `moveMouseHandler` where `isActive` is false is still attached to the window, regardless of the current state.

This is why the "exhaustive-deps" hook is warning you about `useEffect` - some of its dependencies can change, without causing the hook to rerun and update those dependencies.

---

#### Fixing it

Since the hook indirectly depends on `isActive`, you *could* fix this by adding `isActive` to the `deps` array for `useEffect`:

```
// Works, but not the best solution
useEffect(() => {
    //...
}, [box, isActive])
```

However, this isn't very clean: if you change `mouseMoveHandler` so that it depends on more state, you'll have the same bug, unless you remember to come and add it to the `deps` array as well.  (Also the linter won't like this)

The `useEffect` function indirectly depends on `isActive` because it directly depends on `mouseMoveHandler`; so instead you can add that to the dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //...
}, [box, mouseMoveHandler])
```

With this change, the useEffect will re-run with new versions of `mouseMoveHandler` which means it'll respect `isActive`.  **However** it's going to run too often - it'll run every time `mouseMoveHandler` becomes a new function instance... which is every single render, since a new function is created every render.

We don't really need to create a new function every render, only when `isActive` has changed: React provides the `useCallback` hook for that use-case.  You can define your `mouseMoveHandler` as

```
const mouseMoveHandler = useCallback(e => {
   if(isActive) {
       // ...
   }
}, [isActive])
```

and now a new function instance is only created when `isActive` changes, which will then trigger `useEffect` to run at the appropriate moment, and you can change the definition of `mouseMoveHandler` (e.g. adding more state) without breaking your `useEffect` hook.

---

This likely still introduces a problem with your `useEffect` hook: it's going to rerun every time `isActive` changes, which means it'll set the box center point every time `isActive` changes, which is probably unwanted.  You should split your effect into two separate effects to avoid this issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // update box center
}, [box])

useEffect(() => {
   // expose window methods
}, [mouseMoveHandler, mouseUpHandler]);
```

---

#### End Result

Ultimately your code should look like this:

```
const mouseMoveHandler = useCallback(e => {
    /* ... */
}, [isActive]);

const mouseUpHandler = useCallback(e => {
    /* ... */
}, [isActive]);

useEffect(() => {
   /* update box center */
}, [box]);

useEffect(() => {
   /* expose callback methods */
}, [mouseUpHandler, mouseMoveHandler])
```

#### More info:

Dan Abramov, one of the React authors goes into a lot more detail in his [Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) blogpost.

Answer (score 4):

[React Hooks useState+useEffect+event gives stale state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154186/react-hooks-usestateuseeffectevent-gives-stale-state).
seems you are having similar problems. basic issue is that **"it gets its value from the closure where it was defined"**

try that **Solution 2 "Use a ref"**. in your scenario

Add below **useRef**, and **useEffect**

```
let refIsActive = useRef(isActive);
useEffect(() => {
    refIsActive.current = isActive;
});
```

then inside mouseMoveHandler , use that ref

```
 const mouseMoveHandler = (e) => {    
  console.log('isActive',refIsActive.current);
    if (refIsActive.current) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an NPM module to solve it `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref` and it seems that it may help and answer your question how to fire the current state.

It's a combination of useState and useRef, and let you get the last value like a `ref`

**Example of use:**

```js
    const [isActive, setIsActive,isActiveRef] = useStateRef(false);
    console.log(isActiveRef.current)
```

More info:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref