# Functional Component data not re-rendering on update in Framer Preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framerjs

I am making a list view which dynamically has to change every few seconds when the data source list updates.

The list from where it is getting the data is essentially

```
const area = [a1,a2,a3,.....,a50]
```

From this list, I `setState([])` of another list - *region* which is rendered into a Frame using `array.map`

I tried various methods from https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component

I am using `useEffect()`to make changes to the array *regions* which is supposed to be rendered

```
export function DynamicList() {
    const [region, setRegion] = React.useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            //take a random integer between 0 and length of the main array - areas

            // if it already exists in the smaller array - regions, then delete it at that index
            if (region.indexOf(areas[randNum]) != -1) {
                // find the index to delete
                delIndex = region.indexOf(areas[randNum])
                console.log(areas[randNum] + " " + delIndex)

                //delete the item at that index
                region.splice(delIndex, 1)
            }

            // adding the random itemt o first position
            region.splice(0, 0, areas[randNum])
            region.join()

            setRegion(region)
            console.log(region)
        }, 6000)
}, [])
}
```

**Console.log is functioning and I see the *Region* array being updated, but it does not render in the preview section**

The part for rendering the UI is

```
return(
   <Stack>
   {region.map((item, index) => {
       return (
           <Frame
            background=""
            key={index}
            defaultValue={item}
            height={10}
            width={200}
            radius="4%"
            color="ffffff"
            style={{
                fontFamily: "Lato",
                fontSize: 10,
            }}
            >
                {item}
            </Frame>
        )
    })}
  </Stack>
)
```

I expect in the preview, cities to keep updating with every new city being added to *region* array showing above the already existing list.

**EDIT : SOLVED. ANSWER BELOW**

Comment: where and how you updated the `region` array?

Comment: Harish, I am updating the ```region``` array every 6 seconds in ```useEffect``` using ```SetInterval```. I am updating the region array and then passing it through ```setRegion()```

Comment: Is your rendering logic and `DynamicList` are in the same functional component?
from the question, it seems to be separate.
Or can you post your complete rending component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Hooks useState+useEffect+event gives stale state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154186/react-hooks-usestateuseeffectevent-gives-stale-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution entailed setting region differently.

with `setRegion(region)` region does not get to know that change has been made to the array. 
Therefore, using `setRegion([...region])` copies the *temp* Region to Region.

Thus code becomes

```
useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
    randNum = Math.floor(0 + Math.random() * areas.length)

    // if it already exists, then delete it
    if (region.indexOf(areas[randNum]) != -1) {
         // find the index to delete
         delIndex = region.indexOf(areas[randNum])
         console.log(areas[randNum] + " " + delIndex)
         //delete the item at that index
         region.splice(delIndex, 1)
    }

    // adding the random itemt o first position
    region.splice(0, 0, areas[randNum])

    // region.join()
    setRegion([...region])
    console.log(region)
    }, 2000)

}, [region])
```