# Why does listing a variable as a dependency "solve" the stale closure problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm trying to understand the general advice I've seen regarding [React and stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

Specifically, as I understand it, the term "stale closure" is used to describe a scenario where a component and `useEffect` function are constructed like this

```
function WatchCount() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(function() {
    setInterval(function log() {
      console.log(`Count is: ${count}`);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1) }>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

React calls `WatchCount` to render a component, and sets the value of the `count` variable. When javascript calls the `log` function two seconds later, the `count` variable will be bound to the `count` variable from when `WatchCount` was first called.  The value of `count` won't reflect updates that may have happened on renders of `WatchCount` that happened in-between the first render and the interval code eventually firing.

The general advice that's given to "solve" this is to list your variable in the dependencies array -- the second argument to `useEffect`

```
useEffect(function iWillBeStale() {
  setInterval(function log() {
    console.log(`Count is: ${count}`);
  }, 2000);
}, [count]);
```

As a javascript programmer, I don't understand how this "solves" the problem.  All we've done here is create an array that includes the variable in it, and passed that array to `useEffect`  My naive view is that the `count` variable in `log` is still scoped to the first call of `WatchCount`, and should still be stale.

Am I missing some nuance of javascript's scope here?

Or does this "fix" things because of something that `useEffect` is doing with those variables?

Or some third thing?

Comment: "*All we've done here is create an array that includes the variable in it, and passed that array to `useEffect`*" - do you understand what `useEffect` uses this array for? But yes, you're right, it doesn't affect the closure, the closed-over constant keeps its value.

Comment: Notice that react runs the entire render function each time the state changes, which creates a new closure and passes it to `useEffect` again. And notice that the second snippet in your answer is not the complete solution as it was found in the article you linked.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now @bergi, thank you.  I wasn't paying close attention to the code, I was only paying attention to the words. :)

Looking at the code in the solution I now see that the `useEffect` function is returning a function.  It's my understanding a function returned from `useEffect` is a cleanup function that runs when the component unmounts, and before running the effects from the previous render.  This cleanup function calls `clearInterval`, which means the log function with the stale closure will never run.  Happy to "accept as best" if some person wants to answer officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing some nuance of javascript's scope here?

No, you're right, creating the array and passing it to `useEffect` doesn't affect the closure, the closed-over constant keeps its value.

> Or does this "fix" things because of something that `useEffect` is doing with those variables?

Yes. React runs the entire render function each time the state changes, which creates a new closure and passes it to `useEffect` again. When the dependencies change, `useEffect` re-runs the effect function which creates a new interval with the new closure.

Also, the effect function is returning a cleanup function in [the author's solution](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#31-useeffect), which runs when the component unmounts or before running the effect the next time (when the dependencies change). This cleanup function calls `clearInterval`, which means the stale closure won't be executed again, and the number of concurrently active intervals doesn't increase.

Admittedly, this proposed solution has a huge bug: clearing the interval and starting a new interval every time the `count` changes does not lead to a nice periodic 2s interval, the gaps between two logs might be much larger - the logging is essentially debounced and will only run if no increment happened in the last 2s. If this is not desired, a ref might be a much simpler solution:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const countRef = useRef(0);
countRef.current = count;

useEffect(function() {
  setInterval(function log() {
    console.log(`Count is: ${countRef.current}`);
  }, 2000);
}, []);
```

Comment: then, the old `count` value disappeared of interval thanks to the new closure that captures the new `count` , right?

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't disappear, the old closure still closes over the old `count`. It has nothing to do with the new closure being created. It's just that React does stop the old effect (via the cleanup function that calls `clearInterval`), so the old closure with the old value is no longer used.

Comment: great, now I understand @Bergi, I have a doubt when the closure is created. The `log()` function creates the closure until useEffect is executed, and the callback passed to useEffect creates the closure as soon as the function component is executed, right?

Comment: i.e. `log()` is executed until the callback passed to useEffect is executed.

Comment: The closure is created when the function is defined, i.e. when the function expression is evaluated.

Comment: It does not matter when (in this case `log()` is executed at a future time) the function is defined (evaluated) because the "capture of its variables" is always "evaluated" by the lexical scope, ¿right? thanks @Bergi

Comment: @Daniel true that