# Ref callbacks - use cases and pitfalls of this pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optimization, design-patterns

## About

This isn't a problem, just trying to gain more insight into an idea which some colleagues and I thought was cool.

We are able to achieve fewer re-renderings by using the function below rather than `useCallback`.

Imagine a bigger codebase, with callbacks that gets propagated from child to grand child over many levels.

> This solution allows the creation of memoized callbacks that run in a scope which may change, but which does not change the reference to the callback itself.

Please take a close look at the following function (and yep, `callbackContainer.current = callback` is meant to be there)

```
function useStableCallback<T>(callback: () => T) {
  const callbackContainer = useRef(callback);
  callbackContainer.current = callback;
  return useCallback(() => callbackContainer.current(), [callbackContainer]);
}
```

### Why this pattern?

##### Let me start with an example of how this was a non-issue with class components

With React class components it was easy to give child components stable callback functions as props.

In the following example the child component (`MyChildComponent`) receives a stable reference to a callback than can be used to refresh some data.

> **Point**: The child component uses a function that depends on state which the
> child component itself does ***NOT*** depend on, (i.e. `this.props.url` on the parent).

If the parent receives a new url, this doesn't cause re-rendering of the child. Because the `onRefresh` callback exists on the parent object, it **does not change.**

Useful!

```
function MyChildComponent({
  onRefresh,
  title,
  body
}: {
  onRefresh: () => any;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}) {
  return (
    <article>
      <SomeOtherChildComponent title={title} body={body} />
      <button onClick={onRefresh}>Refresh</button>
    </article>
  );
}

interface ParentState {
  title?: string;
  body?: string;
  isLoading: boolean;
}

interface ParentProps {
  url: string;
}

class MyParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentProps> {
  state: ParentState = { isLoading: false };

  refresh = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r =>
        this.setState({
          title: r.title,
          body: r.body,
          isLoading: false
        })
      );
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.isLoading ? (
      <h3>Loading...</h3>
    ) : (
      <MyChildComponent
        title={this.state.title}
        body={this.state.body}
        onRefresh={this.refresh}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

##### Now with hooks

In the following block `MyParentComponent` as been implemented as a function with hooks.

Uh-oh! As we can see, the `refresh`-function will now change every time `MyParentComponent` receives a new url!

```
function MyParentComponent({ url }: ParentProps) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [body, setBody] = useState('');

  const refresh = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setTitle(r.title);
        setBody(r.body);
      });
  }, [url, setIsLoading, setTitle, setBody]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  ) : (
    <MyChildComponent title={title} body={body} onRefresh={refresh} />
  );
}
```

#### With suggested pattern

`refresh` can be defined as follows:

```
const refresh = useStableCallback(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setTitle(r.title);
      setBody(r.body);
    });
});
```

### This is cool because...

- The `refresh` function will never change (and thus won't cause re-renderings)
- It brings some handy functionality from class components into the world of functional components
- The function will always run in the most recent scope of the component in which it was defined. In other words: `refresh` knows about changes to `url`, even though the function itself did not change.

#### Is it a good pattern?

This definitely helps us to avoid a bunch of re-renderings, but **are there any potential problems** with this pattern? What do you think?

Comment: I really like the idea, but "*Opinions are welcome*" is off-topic on StackOverflow so I've rephrased the question a bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't `useCallback` always return the same ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65890278/1048572)

Comment: To gather opinions on the idea, it might be worth submitting it to https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/ (instead of `/r/typescript` as I suggested earlier)

Comment: I think this entry fits better in the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site.