# Class component bind vs. function component useCallback

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

For comparison purpose I wrote same logic as class vs. function component, and noticed some behavioral differences.

Class component with bind:

```js
this.logName = this.logName.bind(this);
```

then function component with `useCallback`:

```js
const logName = useCallback(() => {
   console.log(`Name is - ${state.name}`);
}, [state.name]);
```

Inside these, I'm calling child component (wrapped in `react.memo` for performance):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ChildComp = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child render");
    setState((state) => state + 1);
  }, [props]);
  return (
    <div className="child">
      <h4>Child Comp ({state})</h4>
      <button onClick={props.log}>Log Name </button>
    </div>
  );
};

//export default ChildComp;
export default React.memo(ChildComp, (p, n) => p.log === n.log);
```

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-vaughan-tf5h5h?file=/src/index.js)

If I update age, due to `react.memo` it doesn't re-render child, it's expected and working fine in both, but if I update `state.name` in functional, child re-render (due to dependency in `useCallback`), but doesn't in class. Due to `bind` in class component I always get right value, but can't remove dependency (`[state.name]`) in functional, else I will get old value.

Please help me understand this. Do I need to optimize function component more to get same behavior as class (no child rendering even `state.name` update), and how can I do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't \`useCallback\` always return the same ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890278/why-cant-usecallback-always-return-the-same-ref)

Comment: @EmileBergeron I feel its different than what `Joseph` asked in that question. My questions is more about do we really need that much optimization for performance and if yes, how I can get exact same behavior as class component.

Comment: Classes and functions are different constructs, so naturally, each comes with its own caveats. There's a common misconception with React that a re-render is always bad, but it's only the case if the output changes (or side-effects re-run on render). React will render a child component, see that it doesn't trigger any changes and will bail out, not rendering the entire tree and not changing the DOM. In your example though, you're preventing this optimization by setting the state on each render through a dependency on the whole `props` object.

Comment: However, callbacks are a common source of issues with React function components with things such as [stale state being captured in callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55154186/1218980) and the different [ways to solve it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55565444/1218980).

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks for explanation and my understand is also the same. FYI, tried without `setState` and `useEffect` also using `useRef`.  eg - `const count = useRef(0);  count.current = count.current + 1;`  then also child re-render in functional component

Comment: Yes, the child will re-render, but if it was a bigger tree, at some point down the tree, React would bail out. And even if React was not bailing out, a render pass isn't an issue in itself if it does not output anything different, it won't mutate the DOM, so it's not as slow as we might think.

Comment: The child still re-renders since the props changed. The children of that child might not re-render if their props were to not change. And in the end, it might not mutate the DOM at all.