# Ag grid prevents access to current value of React state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

```
const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(moment().format('DD/MM/YY'));

function generateColumnDefs(columnDefs) {
  return columnDefs.map(columnDef => {
      if (columnDef.field === 'lob') {
        Object.assign(columnDef, {
          cellRendererFramework: lobLinkRenderer
        });
      }   
    return columnDef;
  });
}

function lobLinkRenderer(params) {
    return (
      <a onClick={() => handleClick(params)}>{params.value}</a>
    );
}

const test=()=>{
    return fromDate;
};

const handleClick = (params) => {
   let myDate1 = fromDate;
   let myDate2 = test();
}

return (
  <div>
     ...
     <button onClick={handleClick}>Test me </button>
  </div>
)
```

The above code is part of a React component that builds an `agGrid` grid. The content of a certain column is being transformed to hyperlinks through `cellRendererFramework`. Once clicked on these hyperlinks `handleClick` is invoked and populates `myDate1` and `myDate2`. ***What is totally unexplained to me is why fromDate does not have its current value***. In the above described case, it always have the initial value offered by `useState` and not the current one despite the number of changes in the state variable's value. At the same time, if clicking on `Test me` button, I am getting the right value for `fromDate`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see these answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156813/13129018
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643670/13129018

Based on the code you've provided, I would recommend binding `fromDate` to a `useRef` container:

```
const fromDateRef = useRef(null);

fromDateRef.current = fromDate;
```

In your methods where you are referencing `fromDate`, replace it with `fromDateRef.current`:

```
const test=()=>{
    return fromDateRef.current;
};

const handleClick = (params) => {
   let myDate1 = fromDateRef.current;
   let myDate2 = test();
}
```

Comment: `refContainer` sounds like a bad name c.f. `fromDateRef`...

Comment: Yes. That works. Could you please add some details to your answer and explain why that happens?

Comment: I had this issue before, this was the fix for me. Please see the answer here for an explanation (I'll add it on top of my answer as well): 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847594/react-hooks-accessing-up-to-date-state-from-within-a-callback/60643670#60643670 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156813/13129018